# Find number of possible root values for an n nodes avl tree

Tags: trees

Be an avl tree with 20 nodes with values from 1 to 20. What are the possible values for the root node. ? I was thinking to find minimum and maximum height but I don't know what to do after that. Does anybody have an idea?

UPDATE:
THe problem is to find the possibles values for root nodes. 
I have to respond to the following questions:

Can 1 value be the values of root node?

Can 2 value be the values of root node?

...

Can 20 value be the values of root node?

Comment: @YvesDaoust How is meaningless. This is a real problem

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding.

Comment: @YvesDaoust so no -1:)))

Comment: Hint: the extreme values are found when all nodes are maximally imbalanced one a side or the other.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i will try to draw that to see. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum and maximum number of nodes in an AVL tree of height $h$ is as follows:
$$\begin{array}{l|cc|}
h&0&1&2&3&4&\ldots\\
\hline
\min&0&1&2&4&7&\ldots\\
\max&0&1&3&7&15&\ldots
\end{array}$$

So when the left subtree has height $3$ and the right subtree has height $4$ then in the extreme unbalanced case the left and righ subtrees have $4$ and $15$ nodes respectively. Together with the root this makes $20$ nodes in total. Therefore the value at the root is at least $5$. A similar argument shows, swapping left and right, that the value at the root is at most $16$.

Comment: How it is possible for a height of 3 the minimum number of nodes to be 4. I tried to draw such a tree but it is not possible.

Comment: I find your mistake. You shift the rows with minimum and maximum. The Minimum and maximum for h(0) is 1.

Comment: I counted height in numbers of nodes on a path, not the number of edges.